my windows forms text is transparent when its not supposed to be
this is what it looks like when built
this is what its supposed to look like
i have no idea whats wrong its only in this project, i have used all these fonts before, the text is not transparent either
anyone who knows whats wrong
i have tried looking through all the properties and couldn't find anything that could lead to this, nothing i did worked

Have you tried it on another system? Or copied your dialog to a new project? I.e. something minimally reproducible? The title looks to have color fringes, that could maybe indicate some problem with cleartype.

Are trying to show that text and the textimage aren't filled but just outlined but you want them to be filled with white color?

Have you changed the TransparencyKey of the hosting Form? If so, reset that property

I looks like there is a problem with ClearType. Also, probably nothing is transparent. The font lines are just thinner than one pixel. Try to use anti-aliasing to fix the problem. It is hard to give you precise advice as you have not explained what you are actually doing.
